# What does process exit code 1181 :"The journal entry has been deleted from the journal" means

Tags: c#

HI,

I am forking process in a thread (c#) , some process exit with exitcode 1181,
what could be the reason?

The process calls link.exe for linking the object files

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Journal Entries remind me of the ext file system. What System are you using, Linux, Windows, Mac? a Different one?

It seems that one of the files you are working on has lost its entry in the Master File Table or whatever else we call it. If you could be a bit more specific about your problem (what exactly does link do? how do you pass it the date for which files to "link"?) maybe you will get a more specific answer.